# Graphics are creating an error when I attempt to knit in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am attempting to knit a pdf document using R-Markdown. It appears the issue I'm having is directly related to me trying to put histograms in my paper. I attempted to knit the document without the histograms and it rendered fine, but once I added the histogram code I keep on getting the following error:

```
output file: Final_Version_1_-_Assignment_1_-_STA304.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: File `Final_Version_1_-_Assignment_1_-_STA304_files/figure-latex
/Q2_part_a_call' not found.

Error: Failed to compile Final_Version_1_-_Assignment_1_-_STA304.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Final_Version_1_-_Assignment_1_-_STA304.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

For reference here is the R-Markdown Code:

```
---
title: "Stats - Assignment 1"
author: "John Doe"
date: "September 26, 2019"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---


``{r setup, include=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)

pop = c(1,0,0,4,1,6,6,3,5,3,1)
population = data.frame(pop)

``
Question 2) a) The following is a histogram of the population data:

``{r Q2_part_a_code, include = FALSE}
#Assignment 1 - Q2 - part a) 

#Please enter the data frame being used and the column to be analyzed. Both without quotation marks.

  population_histogram = function(df_for_use,column_to_analyze){

  pop_histo = ggplot(data = df_for_use) + geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = column_to_analyze), binwidth = 0.5)


  print(pop_histo)

    }
``


``{r Q2_part_a_call), include = TRUE}
population_histogram(population,pop)
``
```

Note: I just put double ticks here so the code chunk wouldn't clash with the markdown on this page. I'm aware it is three ticks for functions.

The code works fine if I just execute from within the R-Markdown window, but once I try to knit a pdf I get the above error.

***EDIT:**  After more playing around it is definitely an issue with the histogram. When I tried to knit an MS Word document it decided to skip the histogram. It did successfully knit the whole document as html.

Comment: The bracket in the chunk label might be causing issues: `Q2_part_a_call)`. Try removing it.

Comment: You are a God....Thank you! It worked!!